# MySQL And C applications

Tags: c++, c, linux, coding-style, mysql4

When building a application that accesses a MySQL database on linux using C/C++ i have to dynamically link into the mysql client library.  Is there a way in which i can statically link the application so that the mysql client libraries are no longer required?

What is the best practice, with regards to C\C++ development, to include rather long queries in the application but outside the code?  Using stored procedures an not possible as the database runs on a MySQL 4 server.

Comment: please split this into two questions

Answer (score 1):

Should be easy to create the static mysql client libs.  If you downloaded the source, you just need to make sure you configure it appropriately:
./configure --enable-static
This should build libmysql/libmysqlclient.a (or possibly libmysql/.libs/libmysqlclient.a) which should be easy to link statically into your executable.

You'll need your executable to be licensed under the GPL or you'll need to buy an appropriate license from the MySQL folks.

Answer (score 0):

The following compile command-line worked for me to statically link the mysql client libs:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql -c mysql.c
gcc -o mysql mysql.o -static -lmysqlclient -static-libgcc -lm -lz -lpthread
```

However, I received the following warnings, which may or may not be a problem for you. It seems to be saying that there is a dependency on the target machine having the same glibc version as your build machine.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../lib/libmysqlclient.a(mf_pack.o): In function `unpack_dirname':
(.text+0x6cc): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../lib/libmysqlclient.a(libmysql.o): In function `read_user_name':
(.text+0x5ed7): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../lib/libmysqlclient.a(mf_pack.o): In function `unpack_dirname':
(.text+0x6e1): warning: Using 'endpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../lib/libmysqlclient.a(my_gethostbyname.o): In function `my_gethostbyname_r':
(.text+0x3c): warning: Using 'gethostbyname_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../lib/libmysqlclient.a(libmysql.o): In function `mysql_server_init':
(.text+0x695d): warning: Using 'getservbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```